# Add parameter to getPriceHtml ( )

Tags: price, magento-1.6

For up and crosssell i want to add a parameter to getPriceHtml.

this is the current call :

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
```

i want to add a new parameter TRUE(default) or FALSE so i can hide certain elements in catalog/product/price.html. So my call becomes :

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related', false) ?>
```

Where ( or better : HOW ? ) do I define this new parameter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is defined in the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`.
Unfortunately for you, this class is never instantiated and you cannot rewrite it as a normal class.
You will have to copy it in `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php` and do your modifications there.
I feel dirty recommending this, but there is no other easy way of doing it.

Let's say your new parameter is called `$showStuff`. Feel free to change it.
After you cloned the file in the location I mentioned, change the method `getPriceHtml` to this:

```
public function getPriceHtml($product, $displayMinimalPrice = false, $idSuffix = '', $showStuff = true)
{
    $type_id = $product->getTypeId();
    if (Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($product)) {
        $realPriceHtml = $this->_preparePriceRenderer($type_id)
            ->setProduct($product)
            ->setDisplayMinimalPrice($displayMinimalPrice)
            ->setIdSuffix($idSuffix)
            ->setShowStuff($showStuff) //add this line
            ->toHtml();
        $product->setAddToCartUrl($this->getAddToCartUrl($product));
        $product->setRealPriceHtml($realPriceHtml);
        $type_id = $this->_mapRenderer;
    }
    return $this->_preparePriceRenderer($type_id)
        ->setProduct($product)
        ->setDisplayMinimalPrice($displayMinimalPrice)
        ->setIdSuffix($idSuffix)
        ->setShowStuff($showStuff) //add this line
        ->toHtml();
}
```

Now you can modify the price templates `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/price.phtml`, `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml` (for bundle) and `price_msrp_*` files (good luck with that) and just take into account the value of your parameter.
You can access the value of your parameter in the templates like this:

```
$showStuff = $this->getShowStuff();
```

Comment: Solved with help of this answer. thnx!